# How to load routing module in angular 17 for RouterModule.forChild

Tags: angular, router, angular17, angular-lazyloading

I need to covert my Angular 16 project into Angular 17
And I used the routing module for lazy loading in Angular 16
my Angular 16 code was like this

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [DashboardComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                component: DashboardComponent,
            },
        ]),
    ],
})


I just need this into Angular 17


Thanks in Advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [{path:'', component: DashboardComponent}];
@NgModule({
    declarations: [DashboardComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
        ],
    exports: [RouterModule]    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

Try this on

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation : https://angular.dev/guide/ngmodules/lazy-loading

Now, to link childs, You need to go in the routes file (where are the root paths) :

> app.routes.ts

And then, link your child (the module child with the children paths inside) to the router as below :

```
export const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => DashboardModule)
}];
```

**Some explanations :**

In this code, I supposed that the name of your module is "**DashboardModule**".

The keyword "**path**" gives you the possibility to choose a prefix for all paths in your DashboardModule.

Then, the keyword "**loadChildren**" is used to connect your child module and the children paths through it.

For all Child modules (with paths indeed) you want to link to the root, you need to add this code fragment in the routes array of the app.routes.ts file.

*(ps: pay attention to the order in which you insert the routes, as usual)*

Regards,